# fatal error Cannot redeclare ru_date в коде PHP

Tags: php

Проблема на сайте следующего вида.

> Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare ru_date() (previously declared in /home/b2220/www/Сайт/include/copy.php:36) in /home/b2220/www/сайт/include/copy.php on line 91

Вот весь код что есть в файле. В чем может быть дело?

```
   <?
function ru_date() {
// Перевод
 $translate = array(
    "am" => "дп",
    "pm" => "пп",
    "AM" => "ДП",
    "PM" => "ПП",
    "Monday" => "Понедельник",
    "Mon" => "Пн",
    "Tuesday" => "Вторник",
    "Tue" => "Вт",
    "Wednesday" => "Среда",
    "Wed" => "Ср",
    "Thursday" => "Четверг",
    "Thu" => "Чт",
    "Friday" => "Пятница",
    "Fri" => "Пт",
    "Saturday" => "Суббота",
    "Sat" => "Сб",
    "Sunday" => "Воскресенье",
    "Sun" => "Вс",
    "January" => "Января",
    "Jan" => "Янв",
    "February" => "Февраля",
    "Feb" => "Фев",
    "March" => "Марта",
    "Mar" => "Мар",
    "April" => "Апреля",
    "Apr" => "Апр",
    "May" => "Мая",
    "May" => "Мая",
    "June" => "Июня",
    "Jun" => "Июн",
    "July" => "Июля",
    "Jul" => "Июл",
    "August" => "Августа",
    "Aug" => "Авг",
    "September" => "Сентября",
    "Sep" => "Сен",
    "October" => "Октября",
    "Oct" => "Окт",
    "November" => "Ноября",
    "Nov" => "Ноя",
    "December" => "Декабря",
    "Dec" => "Дек",
    "st" => "ое",
    "nd" => "ое",
    "rd" => "е",
    "th" => "ое"
 );
 // если передали дату, то переводим ее
 if (func_num_args() > 1) {
 $timestamp = func_get_arg(1);
 return strtr(date(func_get_arg(0), $timestamp), $translate);
 } else {
// иначе текущую дату
 return strtr(date(func_get_arg(0)), $translate);
 }
 }
 print ru_date("Курсы валют на j F Y");
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

В самом файле нет ошибок. Он пишет, что конфликтует с другим подключенным.
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4220a8e5b9ad6fb3951e502700f7f0ca350b87e5

Проверьте его или поделитесь.

Comment: http://pastie.org/10534766 вот весь код в файле

Answer (score 1):

Учите английский и читайте ошибки, не ленитесь.
Написано же, что нельзя переопределять уже объявленные функции и ссылается на строку, где первый раз эту функцию уже объявили.

У вас в этом файле уже есть функция с таким же именем:

```
/home/b2220/www/Сайт/include/copy.php:36
```

Возможно у вас этот файл подключается 2 раза. Смотрите где вы его подключаете и используйте подключение так [require_once()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.require-once.php)

Варианта 4 (на первый взгляд):

1. Используйте уже описанную функцию (если она делает то, что нужно)
2. Именуйте функцию по другому
3. Используйте [пространства имен](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.php)
4. Используйте `ООП`

3 и 4 пункты можно и нужно использовать вместе.

Comment: Переименование функции тоже выдает ошибку. Добавлю, что дата выводится нормально, без ошибок, просто все что за этой функцие на странице попадает в ошибку например счетсчики метрики и аналитикса. В файле кроме этого еще таблица и все.

Answer (score 0):

В функции нет проблем , что то гдето выше , видимо что то инклюдите где уже есть такая функция .